# Flash Player problems on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, flash-player

I'm having a lot of problems with flash player in my win 7 x64 laptop, in YouTube the videos are completely black, you can only hear the sound and in Vimeo the videos are played well in normal size but completely black in fullscreen.

Also some days ago YouTube played normal size videos but with controls not visible.

I'm sure that the problem isn't the browser since this happen in Chrome, Firefox and IE 8.

My laptop is a Dell XPS L501X, the flash version is 10,2,152,26 and the OS is Windows 7 Home Premium with SP1.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling hardware acceleration by right clicking within a flash player instance and selecting "Settings."

As a temporary solution for Youtube, you can enable the HTML5 video viewer by joining the [Youtube HTML5 Trial](http://www.youtube.com/html5).